# error installing Ruby 1.9.1-p431

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, openssl, rvm

I run `rvm install ruby-1.9.1-p431`

I my output is:

```
`ruby-1.9.1-p431 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.1-p431..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: debian/Kali_Linux_Rolling/x86_64/ruby-1.9.1-p431.
It is not possible to build movable binaries for rubies 1.8-1.9.2, but you can do it for your system only.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for debian.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p431, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)
ruby-1.9.1-p431 - #downloading ruby-1.9.1-p431, this may take a while depending on your connection
ruby-1.9.1-p431 - #extracting ruby-1.9.1-p431 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-p431
ruby-1.9.1-p431 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.1/p431/backport-2404.patch.
ruby-1.9.1-p431 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.1/openssl-1.0.patch.
ruby-1.9.1-p431 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.1/nossl2.diff.
ruby-1.9.1-p431 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/ssl_no_ec2m.patch.
ruby-1.9.1-p431 - #configuring
ruby-1.9.1-p431 - #post-configuration
ruby-1.9.1-p431 - #compiling
Error running '__rvm_make -j2',
showing last 15 lines of /root/.rvm/log/1467391016_ruby-1.9.1-p431/make.log
ossl_ssl.c: In function ‘ossl_sslctx_session_remove_cb’:
ossl_ssl.c:410:38: warning: variable ‘ret_obj’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     VALUE ary, sslctx_obj, sess_obj, ret_obj;
                                      ^
ossl_ssl.c: In function ‘ossl_ssl_get_cipher’:
ossl_ssl.c:1226:12: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
     cipher = SSL_get_current_cipher(ssl);
            ^
Makefile:220: recipe for target 'ossl_ssl.o' failed
make[1]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-p431/ext/openssl'
uncommon.mk:134: recipe for target 'mkmain.sh' failed
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.`
```

I also get this error when attempting to install ruby-1.9.3. I have reconfigured openssl to at versions I have installed and nothing has happened. I have also tried updating rvm trying again and trying to install the version through a file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3548#issuecomment-193798735

Comment: Why do you want to install Ruby 1.9? It is deprecated, unmaintained and doesn't get security updates anymore.